# Error al tratar de editar una imagen laravel, vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

tengo el sgt template en donde actualizo los campos `tema, capacitador, conoce y imagen` (la imagen la obtengo desde la carpeta public del proyecto y la muestro en el formulario)

Al querer editar por ejemplo solo el campo `conoce` mas no la imagen que ya fue guardada al ingresar el registro me salta el sigt mensaje  **Formato de archivo no permitido!** "".. ese mensaje lo muestro en la condicion donde solo permito que se suban formatos de archivos de imagen en el metodo `validarDatos`

Como corrigo el mi error que se me presenta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El template donde edito los campos del formulario

```
 <template>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row border">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-12">

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <Label>Tema(*)</Label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="informacion.tema" placeholder="Tema" maxlength="200">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <Label>Capacitador(*)</Label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="informacion.capacitador" placeholder="Capacitador" maxlength="200">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <Label>Conoce(*)</Label>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="200" class="form-control" v-model="informacion.conoce" placeholder="Conoce"> </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <Label>Seleccione la imagen(*)</Label>
                    <input type="file" @change="obtenerImagen" ref="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg" class="form-control file">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <br>
                        <span type="hidden"><img :src="imagen" alt="Imagen a cargar" width="100%" height="100%"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--fin card body-->
<div class="card-body">
    <div><span>Los campos con (*) son obligatorios</span></div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div v-show="errorValidacion" class="form-group row div-error">
            <div class="text-center text-error">
                <div v-for="error in errorMostrarMsj" :key="error" v-text="error">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" @click="cerrarTemplateRegistro()" class="btn btn-primary">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="actualizar()">Actualizar Información</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--fin 2do card body-->
```

El script del formulario

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            informacion: {
                tema: '',
                capacitador: '',
                conoce: '',
                imagenCargar: '',
                imagenMiniatura: '',
                id: '',
            },
            name: '',

            arrayRegistros: [],
            arrayMostrarDatos: [],
            errorMostrarMsj: [],
            errorValidacion: 0,

            template: 1,
            offset: 3,
            criterio: 'tema',
            buscar: '',  
            file: '', 


        }
    },
    computed: {
        imagen(){
            return this.informacion.imagenMiniatura;
        }
    }, 
    methods: {
        obtenerImagen(e){
            this.file = e.target.files[0];//img en la posicion 0
            this.imagenCargar = this.file['name']; //agregamos la informacion
            this.cargarImagen(this.file);

            if (this.validarDatos()) {
                return;
            }
        },
        cargarImagen(file){
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) =>{
                this.informacion.imagenMiniatura = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },


        editar(id) {

            let me = this;
            var url = '/informacion/obtener?id=' + id;
            var arrayEditarDatos=[];
            var ruta = '/informacion/'
            axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                arrayEditarDatos = respuesta.informacion;
                me.informacion.id = arrayEditarDatos[0]['id'];
                me.informacion.tema = arrayEditarDatos[0]['tema'];
                me.informacion.capacitador = arrayEditarDatos[0]['capacitador'];
                me.informacion.conoce = arrayEditarDatos[0]['conoce'];
                me.file = arrayEditarDatos[0]['imagen'];
                me.informacion.imagenMiniatura = 'http://localhost:8000/informacion/' + ''+me.file;

            }).catch((error) =>{
                console.log(error); 
            });

        },
        actualizar(){
            if (this.validarDatos()){
                return;
            }

            let me = this;
            axios.put('/informacion/actualizar', me.informacion)   

            .then((response) => {
                swal({
                    title: 'Información Actualizada!!',
                    type:  'success',
                    text:  'La información a sido actualizada',
                })
            }).catch( (error) =>{
                console.log(error);
            }); 

        },         
        validarDatos() {//Validaciones para el registro de los datos
            this.errorValidacion = 0;
            this.errorMostrarMsj = [];
            if (!this.informacion.tema) this.errorMostrarMsj.push("El tema de la informacion es requerido");
            if (!this.informacion.capacitador) this.errorMostrarMsj.push("El campo capacitador es requerido");
            if (!this.informacion.conoce) this.errorMostrarMsj.push("El campo conoce es requerido");

            if (!this.file) {
                this.errorMostrarMsj.push("Seleccione una imagen para subir");
            } else
            if(this.file['type'] != 'image/png' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpg' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpeg'){
                this.errorMostrarMsj.push("Formato de archivo no permitido!");
                this.file = '';
            }

            if (this.errorMostrarMsj.length) this.errorValidacion = 1;

            return this.errorValidacion;
        },            

    },

}
```

Comment: Entoces no entra en el primer if si no seleccionas ninguna imagen? El que dice `if (!this.file)`

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ no, no entra en ese if..  en vue devtools en file me muestra lo sgt `cZ94oVcamFjvtPqmMCjz.jpg` que es el nombre de la img que esta en la base y en la propiedad computed del metodo imagen tengo `imagen:"http://localhost:8000/informacion/cZ94oVcamFjvtPqmMCjz.jpg"`

Comment: Veo que le asignas valor a `file` en el método  `obtenerImagen`, y ese método es llamado cuando cambia el input file, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero no entiendo por qué a `file` ya le asignas valor si el usuario no cargó ninguna imagen desde el input... Que sucede si quitas esta linea `me.file = arrayEditarDatos[0]['imagen'];` en el método `editar`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ entra al `if (!this.file) ` me pide nuevamente subir la imagen

Comment: entonces quita ese if/else, y deja sólo `if(this.file && (this.file['type'] != 'image/png' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpg' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpeg')) { this.errorMostrarMsj.push("Formato de archivo no permitido!"); this.file = ''; }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sisi lo hice pero entra el ` if(this.file && (this.file['type']` xdd

Comment: Anidalo entonces `if(this.file) { if(this.file['type'] != 'image/png' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpg' && this.file['type'] != 'image/jpeg')) { this.errorMostrarMsj.push("Formato de archivo no permitido!"); this.file = ''; } }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ muchas gracias men ya funciona xd

Comment: si lograste hacerlo funcionar por favor escribe las respuestas explicando cómo lo hiciste, en esta y en la otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331746/error-al-cargar-una-imagen-al-momento-de-editarla-en-un-formulario-laravel-vuej) también